# Create Ember objects from JSON response and display with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm attempting to use Ember to query a JSON API, create Objects out of the data, and then loop through the objects in my Handlebars templates. I'm able to log the `response` as well as the `categories` array and I see them both being created. I keep getting "No categories found" in my template.

**app.js:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Category = Ember.Object.extend();

App.Category.reopenClass({
    list: function() {
        $.getJSON("/api_url").then(function(response) {
                var categories = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    // create a Category with a "name" property
                    categories.push(App.Category.create({ name: response[i]}));
                }
            // see screenshot for what this looks like logged to console
            return categories;
        });
    }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Category.list();
    }
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My App</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">

        <h1>My App</h1>

        <div class="content">
            {{outlet}}
        </div>

        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
            <ul>
                {{#each category}}
                    <li>Name: {{name}}</li>
                    {{else}}
                        <li>No categories found</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </script>

        <script src="/kory/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="/kory/js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
        <script src="/kory/js/libs/ember-1.5.0.js"></script>
        <script src="/kory/js/app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Example JSON response:**

```
[
    "Foo",
    "Bar",
    "Meow",
    "Woof"
]
```

Screenshot of logged `categories` array:
[image: array screenshot]

Comment: in your template, have you tried simply `{{#each}}` instead of `{{#each category}}`?

Comment: Just tried that, i got this error: `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed (generated index controller)`

Comment: Check your `list` method inside of `App.Categories`. This method does not have a return statement so nothing is going to be returned if you call it.

Comment: @Myslik you're right, i had to `return` the getJSON call. Why is it that removing "category" from the each statement fixed it? Is it because I already set the scope in my IndexRoute?

Comment: @kmm exactly as you said. If you return the array in `model` hook in the route, the array is going straight to the `content` of the controller. So there is no `category` property.

Comment: @kmm, the parameter in the `{{#each}}` helper is the property in the controller you want to iterate over.  You don't have a controller, so Ember created one, which does not have a property called `category`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have things setup (which is fine) you should create an IndexController based on the ArrayController class:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});
```

Now your controller can be looped over with the `#each` helper:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each}}
      <li>Name: {{name}}</li>
    {{else}}
      li>No categories found</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Here is a quick JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/wefof/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution was to a problem I was having exactly. I tried to use the solution proposed above but it didnt fix my problem. After a few hours of debugging this problem on my own, I have realized that there was a problem that we were both making! Upon further evaulation, it looked like one of the comments noticed this problem, but I wanted to make this more explicit since a few different people had this trouble across forums with no real solution.

This code:

```
list: function() {
    $.getJSON("/api_url").then(function(response) {
            var categories = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                // create a Category with a "name" property
                categories.push(App.Category.create({ name: response[i]}));
            }
        // see screenshot for what this looks like logged to console
        return categories;
    });
}
```

is asynchronous. Whenever the REST API returns with the JSON, the Ember `category` objects are created and then returned. Since its asynchronous, the model hook invokes the list function, and thinks the call is done.

If the code was modified such that the promise was returned:

```
list: function() {
    return $.getJSON("/api_url").then(function(response) {
            var categories = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                // create a Category with a "name" property
                categories.push(App.Category.create({ name: response[i]}));
            }
        // see screenshot for what this looks like logged to console
        return categories;
    });
}
```

Ember would block the model hook until the promise succeeded or failed because Ember is awesome like that.